# cURL request blocked

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to run a simple cURL function on a PHP website, but for some reason, the request doesnt work.

I have tested the code on a different server and works perfectly fine.
Both sites use same cURL version (7.19.7), same cURL settings. Both use APACHE 2.2.

The site where the function works, uses PHP 5.6

The site where the function doesnt work, uses PHP 5.5.23

But I really dont think it's a PHP version issue, but a server issue.
However, I have no idea what to look for, to debug this and see why it doesnt work. I am simply stuck on this.

My code is this:

```
function curlGet($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ( $result === false ){
        return 'COULD NOT CONNECT';
    }else{
        return $result;
    }
}
echo curlGet('http://www.google.com');
```

Comment: your timeout is only 25 miliseconds try to change it to 500 or something

Comment: Actually the timeout is in seconds, not miliseconds - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Errors? Warning? Notice?

Comment: No, that's the thing ... nothing. No errors, no warnings, no notices.

Comment: I had an error before like this, it's because of safe mode is turned on and curl options won't work.

Comment: @AliTorabi Can you detail this please? You mean php.ini flag, safe_mode? This was removed in PHP 5.4

Comment: Have you used `curl_error`?

Answer (score 1):

Some distributions of php5-curl (like Debian6 iirc) come with a default useragent string, and some don't. I guess that useragentstring-less requests are blocked on your target server. A lot of websites do that for some reason (I don't know why). If this is your problem, solution is CURLOPT_USERAGENT .. Anyway, record the entire coversattion from both clients, find the difference in the requests, and luke them out. (Fiddler Proxy is great for this. Even allow MITM attacks with https SSL/TLS through fake SSL certificates :D )

Comment: Your solutions saved my day after hours of failed retries. However I had to make the connection and curl execution timeout one second, if I used the _MS (millisecond) and set the timeout less than a second long it doesn't work though the request is made to a script existing on the same server.